# SQL query for the same table

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a table in oracle with columns like ID and J_Code

```
ID             J_Code
---------------------------------------------
1234           C1234
1234           FGH89
1234           BNMG9
1234           AIOBN

7890           CVBN0
7890           FGHJK
7896           LKJHIN
```

I need to write a sql query which would return me count where J_code starts with C but not with A for a given ID. At runtime we would pass ID. So when ID=1234, the count should be 0 as we do have 'AIOBN' there. But when I pass 7890 the count should be 1. Is this possible using a nested query or self join ?

Comment: Where is SQL Query you atleast tried yourself ?

Comment: ` So when ID=1234, the count should be 0 as we do have 'AIOBN' there.` Hello, here count should be 1 NOT 0 , as at 1st spot there is C1234

Comment: You should choose either MySQL or Oracle, not both.

Comment: So you are wanting to add to the count when there is a C and subtract from the count where there is an A?

Comment: Do you mean: for any given group of rows for a _'given id'_: 1) There MUST be row that has a `J_CODE` starting with 'C', 2) There MUST NOT be another row that has a `J_CODE` starting with 'A'? Would that be useful in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use following:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM your_table WHERE J_Code NOT LIKE 'a%' AND ID = your_id
```

Comment: Yes I did that.... But now I also want to check that there should not be an entry for J_Code  like 'A%'

Comment: where J_code starts with C but not with A for a given ID. this condition your query also return 1234 result 1.

Comment: @MukeshKalgude , please read question Again ! And read answer again, and analyze it as it is correct.

Comment: @MukeshKalgude and read my comment Below question which already says  -> `So when ID=1234, the count should be 0 as we do have 'AIOBN' there.` Hello, here count should be 1 NOT 0 , as at 1st spot there is C1234`

Comment: @MukeshKalgude , got it , His question Does not make any sense , so yes correct so query should be ONLY -> `not like 'a%' AND id = your_id`

Comment: It should not only not like 'a%' work both are required.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't know about the oracle syntax, as per SQL Server, query could be :-

```
Select   t.id
        ,Sum(Case When t.j_code like 'c%' Then 1 Else 0 End) As cCount
From    table As t 
Group By t.id
Having Sum(Case When t.j_code like 'a%' Then 1 Else 0 End) = 0 
        And Sum(Case When t.j_code like 'c%' Then 1 Else 0 End) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The question appears to ask:

- for any given *Group* of rows for a 'given id' e.g. 7890:
- 1) There MUST be row that has a J_CODE starting with 'C'
- 2) There MUST NOT be another row that has a J_CODE starting with 'A'

This indicates that ALL the rows belonging to a *Group* e.g. 1234 must be checked.

In the test data supplied:

- *Group* 1234 has 1 row starting with 'C' and also a separate row that starts with 'A'.
- *Group* 7890 has 1 row starting with 'C' and *does not* have a row that starts with 'A'.

Required:

- The *Group 1234* to be 'invalid' because it contains an 'A' row.
- The *Group 7890* to be 'valid' because it *DOES NOT* contain an 'A' row.

There is an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ff9bb/1)

I chose to use a 'correlated' sub query to check for the existence of the 'A' record.

I use 'mysql' but it is standard SQL so should work anywhere.

The code:

```
/* http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ff9bb/1 */

SET @whichId = 7890;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Q3089887 `JCode_C`
WHERE 
       `JCode_C`.`ID` = @whichId
AND    `JCode_C`.`J_Code` LIKE 'C%' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM Q3089887 `JCode_A`
                WHERE `JCode_A`.`ID` = `JCode_C`.`ID`
        AND   `JCode_A`.`J_Code` LIKE 'A%'
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

try this query

```
select Count(id)
from table1
where j_code like 'c%'
and id not in(select id from table1 where j_code like 'a%' )
and id=1234
```

Comment: There is no need of 2nd condition `not like 'a%' `as it already checks for j_code ONLY starting from letter `c`

Comment: Read condition carefully

Comment: If it starts with C then it will never start with A.  This still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Patrick yes correct so query should be ONLY -> not like 'a%' AND id = 12345677890

Comment: @MukeshKalgude, pls remove `where j_code like 'c%'` as he wants code starting from any  letter OTHER than a

Comment: Ok let me reframe. The ID column can have same Ids for which we have have J_codes with C P A or any albhabet. I want to return the count as 1 if for same Id we have JCode with C but not with A. So If I pass 1234 then i want 0. If i pass 7890, I should get 1

Comment: Your requirement to my query is right.Now what you needed i don't know